# C# Unity - Keep the size of a gameobject on HUD changing Z depth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Camera placed on Position(0,0,0) and Rotation(0,0,0).I want to instantiate a canvas (dynamically) in the FOV of the camera and I want to keep the aspect ratio of the object even if the Z index is changing.

To be more clear I want the canvas to cover the same area at Position(10,5,0) and, for example at Position (10,5,50).

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you are trying to cover. Is it an object in 3D or is it a UI element. You mention canvas but how does it change when you move in z axis if it is a canvas element?

Comment: i'll try to make some screenshots

Comment: you would need to adjust the scale by checking the worldtoscreenpoints as a starting point

Comment: @BugFinder can you be more specific to help me to search a tutorial or guide?

Comment: We dont point people to tutorials  ..you've got the function you can read the unity docs on how to use it

Comment: I'll keep in mind. TY!